# The value of $b$ for which $f(x)=\sin x-bx+c$ is always decreasing for all values of x is?

Tags: functions

$$f'(x)=\cos x-b$$
and for the function to be decreasing
$$f'(x)\le0$$
Please help me proceed further.

Comment: You want derivative to be negative. Since range of cos x is [-1,1], any value of b greater than 1 will make derivative negative and original function decreasing.

Comment: Shouldnt it be b>= 1

Comment: Yes, b>=1 is ok. Derivative can be 0 if you need decreasing function. If you want strictly decreasing function (constants are not allowed), then b must be >1.

Answer (score 5):

For the function to be decreasing, $f'(x)\leq0$ should hold, not $f'(x)\geq0$.

Furthermore, the inequality should hold for **all** values of $x$, meaning that your original question has been reduced to:

> For what values of $b$ does the inequality $\cos x - b\leq 0$ hold for all $x$?

And the answer should be quite simple, since you know that $\cos x$ takes the values between $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: So accordingly, b>=1 ?

Comment: @Drishtinarula Precisely.